# Angular localhost - URL not found in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, internet-explorer-11

We use Azure AD to authenticate in our Angular Application. We have a "reply URL" with a very long token which results in a 404 in Internet Explorer but not in other browsers.

The problem only occurs in local development:

http://localhost:4200/refresh#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV... (very long string)

When we deploy the application, the url works just fine:

http://www.example.com/refresh#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV... (very long string)

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Found out what happens.

Settings -> Compatibility View Settings -> Uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"

Now it works